# Mouse position on scaled canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, offset, aspect-ratio

I have a canvas with 100% `width` and `height`.

It is part of a remote desktop I am working on. Currently I am stuck because the mouse position does not reflect the position on the canvas correctly.

When I send the data to the desktop I have to compensate for different screen sizes.

```
var x = Math.floor( mouse.x / canvas.width * 100 ); 
var y = Math.floor( mouse.y / canvas.height * 100 );
```

However when I try draw on the canvas with those `x` and `z` values I am not getting the correct positions.

The reason that I need the canvas / am trying to use percentage is that it is going to be an overlay on top of a video. And the user has to draw a rectangle around the video to get an offset because videos often display black sidebars for aspect ratios.

Here is a example of the canvas that does not put the rectangle in the right position:

http://jsfiddle.net/74CP8/

*Edit: FYI: Firefox does not seem to run the jsfiddle properly due to the way jsfiddle works apparently. Try Chrome.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20061533/856501 might help, it's a post i made about getting coordinates, which works when using css scaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want, but here it is 2 possible solutions :

The first allows you to move correctly your mouse in a scaled canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/74CP8/1/

The second allows you to draw a rectangle from the top left corner to the bottom right corner.

http://jsfiddle.net/74CP8/2/

Your problem was here :

```
ctx.rect(x,y,x+10, y+ 10)
```

You used x & y as percentages whereas you need its as pixels.

Don't hesitate if you have any other questions.

Comment: They work great! Thanks for the answer! Could you tell me what part you don't understand so I can edit my question?

Comment: I'm happy that it suits you. 
I was not sure whether the user has to click, then moves the mouse and releases the click to draw the rectangle or just draw it as my solution 2 suggest.

Comment: Yeah. That is the end goal. But I figured I can find that out myself after :p

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question. How do you deal with offsets? 0,0 to mouse position works fine. But anywhere else and the rect will shoot further than the mouse position.
http://jsfiddle.net/74CP8/3/

Comment: Also resizing the browser after the script has loaded "confuses" the code